# Get percentage of a letter in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

In the given dictionary, each key is a single lowercase letter and each value is the number of lowercase words that start with that letter. The str parameter is a single lowercase letter. Based on the values in the dictionary, return the percentage of words that start with that letter.

Note: use floating-point division.

```
def get_letter_percentage(dictionary, s):
   '''(dict of {str : int}, str) -> float'''

# Start with a counter for the sum of the values.
count = 0
# And then look at the key and value of the dictionary
for (key, value) in dictionary.items():
```

This is where I got stuck. I know I need to create a sum of the values in order to do a floating point division.

```
# guessing it is something along these lines
count = len(values) #??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this inside your function:

```
dictionary = {'a': 5, 'b': 8, 'c':15}
sum = 0
for (key, value) in dictionary.items(): sum += value
percentage = dictionary['a'] / (sum + 0.0)
print "percentage of '%s' is %.2f %%" % ('a' , percentage*100)
```

Comment: Just realized I need to return a float so I will just get rid of the print statement

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_letter_percentage(dictionary, s):
   '''(dict of {str : int}, str) -> float'''

   return dictionary[s] * 1.0 / sum(dictionary.values())
```

The percentage is the amount of occurrences divided by the total occurrences.
Note the multiplication by 1.0 to avoid int division.

Answer (score 0):

If each value is the number of words for each letter, then your code to find the sum would be:

```
sum = 0
for (key, value) in dictionary:
    sum = sum + value
```

Then it's a case of:

```
def get_letter_percentage(dictionary, letter):
    return dictionary[letter] / sum
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
mydict = {"a":5, "b":1, "c":4, "d":3, "e":6}


def get_letter_percentage(dictionary, s):
    sum = 0
    for key in dictionary:
        sum += dictionary[key]

    return float(dictionary[s]) / float(sum)

print get_letter_percentage(mydict, "b")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_letter_percentage(stats, letter):
  return stats[letter] / (sum(stats.values()) + 0.0)
```